# web.config authorization rules are vulnerable to be bypassed

Tags: asp.net, web-config, asp.net-membership, authorization

I wonder if **authorization** rules I've applied to a directory of website could be **bypassed** ? I mean someone could ( by using any trick or hack ) just get access to the resources without having **privileges** ?

Comment: I don't think this is possible, however bypassing authentication can be done by many ways and if you do that authorization is almost useless

Comment: @AmiramKorach : how ? can you share resources about these?

Comment: How to bypass authentication? Steel password, steel cookie, steel computer... With authorization you are sure you allow only the admin to get into the admin zone, but are you sure he is really the admin? I think authentication is much bigger issue.

Comment: @AmiramKorach : oh yeah , I know these , but now I want to know if someone could ( by tricks like manipulating URLs or request headers or ... ) bypass either authentication or authorization rules defined in web.config . just like there is no limitation .( not by hijacking other users credentials )

Comment: No. I don't think it is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it were possible, we (the ASP.NET team) would be forced to patch it.  We advertise that developers can use URL-based authorization to secure WebForms pages reliably.

You *must not* use URL-based authorization to secure MVC actions or other things that go through the Routing pipeline.  This is because it is very easy to get into a situation where a particular MVC controller or action can be accessed via multiple URLs, and it's often too difficult to figure out every single permutation and shut it down via config.  See the link Eric posted for more info.

Comment: thank you . well I'm using MVP pattern with asp.net WebForms . so still uses pages , hmm it's safe, right ?

Comment: As long as the URL actually maps to a physical file, URL-based authorization is supported.  If it is going through a layer of indirection, URL-based authorization is not supported.

Answer (score 1):

Never rely on web.config to secure an ASP.Net MVC application.  I'm not sure whether the same applies to ASP.Net Web Forms.

> You cannot use routing or web.config files to secure your MVC application. The only supported way to secure your MVC application is to apply the Authorize attribute to each controller and use the new  AllowAnonymous attribute on the login and register actions. Making security decisions based on the current area is a Very Bad Thing and will open your application to vulnerabilities.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rickandy/archive/2012/03/23/securing-your-asp-net-mvc-4-app-and-the-new-allowanonymous-attribute.aspx